# How to update particular section using action region

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionsupport, action, actionregion

Here when i update the "Record Detail" section ,first section "Account information" validation error is throwing.how to update only the particular section through action region?
[image]

**visualforce page code:**

```
<apex:form > 
<apex:pageBlock title="Enter your Information" >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Information" collapsible="false" >
<apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!account.accountnumber}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!account.Rating}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!account.industry}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!account.Active__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>

<div align="center">
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveAndCongrat}" value="Save" />
</div>

</apex:pageBlock>


<apex:pageblock title="Record Details" >
<apex:pageblockSection title="Recent Record Details" collapsible="false">

<apex:pageblockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
<apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="update, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
<apex:column headerValue="Name" >
 <apex:outputField value="{!a.name}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="AccountNumber">
  <apex:outputField value="{!a.accountnumber}" />
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Rating">
 <apex:outputField value="{!a.rating}"/>
 </apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Industry">
 <apex:outputField value="{!a.industry}"/>
 </apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Active">
 <apex:outputField value="{!a.Active__c}"/>
 </apex:column>

</apex:pageblocktable>

 <apex:commandButton action="{!quickUpdat}" value="UpdateRecord" />
</apex:pageblockSection>   
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

**Apex code:**

```
public with sharing class saveAndRedirect{
  Account request;
  private Apexpages.standardcontroller controller;
  public saveAndRedirect(Apexpages.standardcontroller controller){
  this.controller = controller;
   }
    public pagereference saveAndCongrat(){
    controller.save();
    pagereference ref = page.Account_custom;
    ref.setRedirect(true);
    return ref;
    }
   private List<Account> acc;
   public String message{get;set;} 
   public List<Account> getacc()
   {
     acc = [select  id,name,accountnumber,rating,industry,Active__c from account ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5];
     return acc;
   } 
    public PageReference quickUpdat(){
    try{
    update acc;
    return ApexPages.CurrentPage();
    }catch(Exception e){
    message='Data Base error during saving...';
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, message));
    return null; }}}
```

Comment: Add rerender to your appropriate command button's

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rerender` attribute as you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm).

You just have to specify an `id` to the section that you want to update on the button click. Here's the "Record details" `pageBlock`. Like this:

```
<apex:pageblock id="recordDetails" title="Record Details" >
```

Then, specify this `id` on the `commandbutton`:

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!quickUpdat}" value="UpdateRecord" rerender="recordDetails" />
```

Comment: i tried,but action is not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: i have done as you said, its not working. records are not updating. action function not running.

Comment: Was it working before adding the rerender attribute?

Comment: if i use only one section it is working, if i go with two section,then section 1 validation error is not allowing to update the section 2.

Comment: Try to replace your return `ApexPages.CurrentPage();` by `return null;` in your `quickUpdat` method.

Comment: not updating , same issue